# How to copy an xml file and rename it and save in the same root directory using c#?

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, linq-to-xml

Do I need to use linq to xml recursively and copy every node and element from one xml to another or is there a better way to directly copy and save it in the same root directory by renaming it? Can anyone give an example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
File.Copy("root.xml", "copy.xml");
```

That copies your xml file and renames it.

Comment: @Krishh: Actually I tried to be funny. Didn't thought, that that was really your question. :D Just thought you didn't phrase your question well enough. ;) But even better if it helped you.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing special about XML files, so just copy it. You don't need to handle anything about XML. Just use [Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
System.IO.File.Copy(pathToFile, pathToCopy);
```